# She gave up her ..[contact, connection, estabishment or attachment].. to feminist ideas?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

This question is in an exercises book in vocabulary section .. in fact I put this question because I'm not sure about the answer. My teacher told me it's "attachment" the book says it's "connection" but I still don't understand this sentence so what do you think this sentence mean? and what do you choose from the brackets?

She gave up her ..[contact, connection, estabishment or attachment].. to feminist ideas

Answer (score 4):

I agree with your teacher, "attachment" is a better answer.

I'm sure as a child you had a favorite blanket or toy. You could say that you were "attached" to it. So, in the sentence, if she gave up her attachment to an idea, that means she doesn't believe in it like she used to.

Connection is an OK word, but not the best. Connection we tend to have with people, not with objects or, in this case, ideas.